# Dockerfile RUN statement doesn't seem to execute

Tags: postgresql, docker

My Dockerfile looks something like this.

```
FROM postgres:12.2

RUN apt-get install -y postgresql-12-cron                     \
 && echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'" >>            \
         /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

The postgresql-12-cron package is installed, though it grumbles about debconf and unable to find Dialog... when I exec into the created container, I can see the package is there.

However the echoed line does not appear at the end of the config file. I thought that apt-get might be returning some non-zero exit code, which would cause the && to not continue to the next statement. I added this line below:

```
RUN echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

This does produce output during the build which looks something like:

```
Step 7/7 : RUN echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'" >> /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

However, after starting and exec-ing into the container, there still are no added lines in the config file.

I'm vaguely aware of other scenarios where this happens, and it's not a syntax error or anything like that, but a misconception on the part of the person writing the Dockerfile on how this works. But I'm coming up empty on Google. What am I missing?

Note: This is a simplified version of the Dockerfile, I'm attempting to echo in more lines than the one I've shown in the example (none of them ever appear).

Update: I added the following line -

```
 && tail -n 10 /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

It produces the following output:

```
shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'
cron.database_name = 'kardashev'
```

There should be 8 lines above this (the config file is pretty massive). But nothing in the output. The file is, at this point, empty, and my creation of the file is blown away before the container actually runs. Ugh. Still clueless as to what that means, though I remember something from a few years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [official `postgres` image Dockerfile](https://github.com/docker-library/postgres/blob/33bccfcaddd0679f55ee1028c012d26cd196537d/12/Dockerfile#L173) declares

```
VOLUME /var/lib/postgresql/data
```

That declaration makes it impossible for any following Dockerfile `RUN` statement to modify any file in that directory tree.

For configuration files like this, a typical path is to make a copy of the config file on the host and then inject it into the container when you start it up; for example

```
docker run -d -p 5432:5432 \
  -v pgdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data \
  -v $PWD/postgresql.conf:/var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf \
  postgres:12.2
```

(Given that you both need to install additional packages and also modify the config file, you'll need to both do this and also build a custom image.)

Comment: Thanks. I see the problem now. Not sure I like the hoops I have to jump through to make this work.

Answer (score 1):

when executing the first part of your query:

```
docker run --rm postgres:12.2 apt-get install -y postgresql-12-cron
```

The container returns

```
E: Unable to locate package postgresql-12-cron
```

and due to the && at the end of your apt-get, it will NEED to succeed before echoing, and if apt-get fails, he will not execute what comes after.

You should fix your package name and retry

Edit:
The package exists, but you need to UPDATE your repos first. 
Your dockerfile should look like this:

```
FROM postgres:12.2

RUN apt-get update \
 && apt-get install -y postgresql-12-cron                     \
 && echo "shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_cron'" >>            \
         /var/lib/postgresql/data/postgresql.conf
```

Comment: I've got an update statement somewhere near the top. It's updated by the time the command runs. I even see `Unpacking postgresql-12-cron (1.2.0-1.pgdg100+1) ...` in the output.

Comment: please provide the full dockerfile then